# SQL Server: Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have no idea why I am getting this error in my stored procedure. For this example, value for `@SearchQuery` will be email:tony.stark@starkindustries.com

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[cust_a91150_sp_LiveSearch]
    @PersonID INT,
    @SearchMode VARCHAR(MAX),
    @SearchQuery VARCHAR(MAX),
    @OrganizationID INT
AS
IF @SearchMode =  'People'
BEGIN
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7
    p.[guid] [id],
    CASE
        WHEN p.[nick_name]+' '+p.[last_name] LIKE @SearchQuery+'%' THEN p.[nick_name]+' '+p.[last_name]
        WHEN p.[first_name]+' '+p.[last_name] LIKE @SearchQuery+'%' THEN p.[first_name]+' '+p.[last_name]
    END AS [name],
    p.[last_name],
    p.[nick_name],
    'Person' [type]
FROM core_person p
LEFT JOIN core_person_email e on e.person_id = p.person_id
WHERE (p.[organization_id] = @OrganizationID)
    AND (p.[first_name] <> '' AND p.[nick_name] <> '')
    AND (p.[record_status] = 0)
    AND (
       (p.[first_name]+' '+p.[last_name] LIKE @SearchQuery+'%' OR p.[nick_name]+' '+p.[last_name] LIKE @SearchQuery+'%' AND @SearchQuery NOT LIKE 'email:%')
    -- Problem here on this next line
    OR (e.[email] = LTRIM(RIGHT(@SearchQuery, LEN(@SearchQuery) - 6)) AND @SearchQuery LIKE 'email:%')
    )
ORDER BY p.[last_name] ASC,
    p.[nick_name] ASC
END
/** End People search mode **/
....
```

I have tried just the main part of the query outside the IF/ELSE by itself and it works fine, no problems. But the moment its run from the stored procedure, it blows up. Please help :(

UPDATE:
Here is the code that is calling the sproc. It's a Web Service call. For this example:

user: 1
mode: "People"
query: "email:tony.stark@starkindustries.com"
orgId: 1

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetResults(string mode, string query)
{
    int user = ArenaContext.Current.Person.PersonID;

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    -- SPROC call on below line
    DataTable DataSource = new LiveSearchServiceModel().LiveSearch_DT(user, mode, query, Arena.Core.ArenaContext.Current.Organization.OrganizationID);
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;

    foreach (DataRow dr in DataSource.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in DataSource.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }

    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

And the database class/method:

```
public class LiveSearchServiceModel : SqlData
{
    public LiveSearchServiceModel() { }

    public DataTable LiveSearch_DT(int user, string searchMode, string searchQuery, int orgId)
    {
        ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

        lst.Add(new SqlParameter("@PersonID", user));
        lst.Add(new SqlParameter("@SearchMode", searchMode));
        lst.Add(new SqlParameter("@SearchQuery", searchQuery));
        lst.Add(new SqlParameter("@OrganizationID", orgId));

        try
        {
            return this.ExecuteDataTable("cust_a91150_sp_LiveSearch", lst);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            lst = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably you are calling the proc incorrectly.   Please show the code where you call the proc.

Comment: Have you debugged it and confirmed that `@SearchQuery` actually contains what you think it does? That error message is consistent with `LEN(@SearchQuery) - 6` being negative

Comment: In addition to the issue you have some serious performance black holes here. The first is it looks like you have multiple execution paths. This can be a very serious performance problem that happens only sometimes. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/ You also have a version of a catch all query. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/

Comment: The code that you have shown looks fine to me.   The most likely explanation is that the `searchQuery` string parameter is not getting populated when you run your app.. but again, that's happening in some part of the code that you are not showing us.

Comment: The suggestion in Lukaz Szozda's answer resolved my issue. It was the length of the variable i was passing in truly was less than 6. Now I need to look into Sean Lange's suggestions and see how I can improve performance. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is with:

```
RIGHT(@SearchQuery, LEN(@SearchQuery) - 6)
```

When you pass something short string you will get:

```
RIGHT(@SearchQuery, -1)
-- Invalid length parameter passed to the right function.
```

I would check if `LEN(@SearchQuery) - 6 >= 0`

```
RIGHT(@SearchQuery, CASE WHEN LEN(@SearchQuery) - 6>=0 THEN LEN(@SearchQuery) - 6
                    ELSE LEN(@SearchQuery) END)
```